# Cmake Error: "QCA's qcatool utility not found"

Tags: c++, cmake, qgis

I'm trying to install QGIS with `sudo make install` but keep getting this error:

```
QCA's qcatool utility not found - aborting
```

Building it from the source worked without any error and I can run QGIS from the build directory.
I'd appreciate any help, thanks!